# Windows Media Player 11 keeps playing after closed?

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

Windows Media Player 11 keeps playing after closed.
What's wrong?

Comment: How long does it play for after you close it?

Comment: @ephilip I don't know because I've never waited for it to finish more than a couple of minutes. I guess it keeps playing till the end of the movie, however.

Comment: open task manager to see if the process of MP11 is running, and try close it to see what hapens

Comment: I have this same problem. It's doing my head in!

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try:

1. Turn off the "Windows Media Player" taskbar toolbar: Right-click the Taskbar, go to Toolbars and uncheck Windows Media Player to turn it off.
2. Open Control Panel, double-click Windows Slideshow, uncheck anything that has to do with Windows Media Player.

Comment: ad 1. Was already unchecked. ad 2. The only option there is *Notify me when new gadgets are installed.* which is checked. Unchecking does not help.

Answer (score 1):

I have a pair of Logitech Z-10 speakers. They have a special function to display the "Now playing" information on a small screen. And they also have play/pause, skip next, previous buttons to control Windows Media Player.

The software that controls the speakers prevents Windows Media Player from closing properly and the music etc is still playing after I close it. So perhaps you have something similar? A Plug-In or something for Media Player that prevents the program from closing.

Comment: This was it! I finally found out and came back to add my answer but it turns out you already added it :)  I have a Logitech G15 keyboard and the software that runs the LCD on that starts a process called "Windows Media Player sideshow gadget" that keeps WMP open. What a pile of junk.